# how to run mysql jdbc connector with source code

Tags: java, java-6, java-5

I want to read mysql jdbc driver souce code, and I download the cource code from [github](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j).

I imported the source code into IntelliJ IDEA, and my jdk version is 1.6. But there are something wrong, such as:
[image]

I read this article:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-installing-source.html, and found this:"Make sure that you have both JDK 1.6.x AND JDK 1.5.x installed. You need both JDKs because Connector/J 5.1 supports both JDBC 3.0 (which has existed prior to JDK 1.6.x) and JDBC 4.0.".

May be the classes which report errors just support jdk version is 1.5, but my jdk version is 1.6.How do I set both jdk1.5 and jdk1.6 in my project?

I searched, but found nothing, any help would be appreciate.

Comment: What is the compiler error that you see in your IDE ?

Comment: "class 'StatementWrapper' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'unwrapper(Class<T>)' in Wrapper"

Comment: The unwrapper method was added since jdk 1.6, may be the StatementWrapper just support jdk1.5, but my jdk is 1.6, so occured this error.

Comment: did you point to 1.6 jdk using project settings ?

Comment: I set 1.6 jdk with Platform settings->SDKs.